# Integrate this function of $\theta$ with respect to $x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have a definite integral which is confusing me:

$$ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin(3\theta)\cos(\theta) \mathrm dx $$

I tried to fiddle with a substitution of $ x=\sin(\theta) $ and tried to go about the question as I would do with a u-substitution question but I got nowhere. Then that got me thinking: what am I supposed to do to integrate something like this where the variable of the function I'm integrating is different to what I'm integrating with respect to?

Also, another side-question is: if the method for this is *not* substitution, why? Why isn't there some kind of substitution for this?

I should probably say that whilst trying to find an answer on how to do this, I stumbled upon someone saying that you should take the stuff with theta out in front of the integral and treat it as a constant and then integrate 1 w.r.t. x but I don't know if this is useful in this case, since this is a definite integral.

Also, the answer on my sheet is $\frac{1}{2} $, if that's of any use.

Comment: I think the fact that the integral is with respect to $x$ instead of $\theta$ is a complete accident. The integral has no numerical value unless it is taken with respect to $\theta$, and when the integral is taken with respect to theta, then it takes on the value of 1/2

Comment: Indeed, I think the question has this mistake in it.

Comment: Quick tip: use `\sin` and `\cos`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not use any substitution for the function as it is independent of $x$

Notice, given that $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin(3\theta)\cos(\theta)\ dx$$

we see that the function $\sin(3\theta)\cos(\theta)$ is being integrated w.r.t. $x$ from $x=0$ to $x=\pi/2$ hence $x$ is variable which does not depend on the function of $\theta$ hence $\sin(3\theta)\cos(\theta)$ is treated as a constant so we have $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin(3\theta)\cos(\theta)\ dx=\sin(3\theta)\cos(\theta)\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ dx$$$$=\sin(3\theta)\cos(\theta)[x]_{0}^{\pi/2}$$$$=\sin(3\theta)\cos(\theta)\left[\frac{\pi}{2}-0\right]$$ $$=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}\sin(3\theta)\cos(\theta)}$$

Comment: Yes, I think this is the correct answer (checked it with Wolfram too) but the answer on my answer sheet was $\frac{1}{2}$ so I think this was a case of a mistake in the question: $dx$ should have been $d\theta$.

Answer (score 2):

If this problem is stated correctly then there are no fancy tricks needed; you are overthinking this one. $ \sin(3\theta)\cos(\theta)$ is a constant *with respect to* $x$. So yes it can be pulled out of the integral. As $x$ changes, $\sin(3\theta)\cos(\theta)$ will not change. An analog to this problem would be to find the derivative of $e^\pi$. A knee-jerk reaction might make some say the derivative must be $e^\pi$ since $e^x$ is its own derivative. But $e^\pi$ is a *constant*, and so the derivative is just $0$. Can you integrate $$ C\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} dx $$ where $C$ is any constant? Try on a few trig identities for your constant and see if you can get some simplifications.

Comment: Actually, I think the question most likely has a mistake in it, see ASKASK's comment.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use the product-to-sum formula:
$$
\sin(3\theta)\cos(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sin(4\theta)+\sin\theta\right).
$$
Now the integral splits up into two pieces; the first vanishes, and the second gives you $1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:*
Let $\simeq$ denote the equality "up to" some constant; then here is yet another way:

$$
\int_{\theta} \sin 3\theta \cos \theta = \int_{\theta} \sin 3\theta D\sin \theta \simeq \sin \theta \sin 3\theta - 3\int_{\theta} \sin \theta \cos 3\theta;\\
-3\int_{\theta} \sin \theta \cos 3\theta = 3\int_{\theta} \cos 3\theta D\cos \theta \simeq 3\cos \theta \cos 3\theta + 9\int_{\theta} \cos \theta \sin 3\theta,
$$
so 
$$
-8 \int_{\theta} \sin 3\theta \cos \theta \simeq 3\cos \theta \cos 3\theta + \sin \theta \sin 3\theta;
$$
this gives $1/2$ as claimed. But the integral $\int_{x=0}^{\pi/2} \sin 3\theta \cos \theta = \frac{\pi}{2}\sin 3\theta \cos \theta$.

Answer (score 0):

You can expand $\sin3\theta$ using the formula for sine of a sum of angles.

$\sin\left(\alpha+\beta\right)=\sin\alpha\cos\beta+\cos\alpha\sin\beta$

$\sin3\theta=\sin\left(2\theta+\theta\right)$

$\sin3\theta=\sin2\theta\cos\theta+\cos2\theta\sin\theta$

Since we're gonna be using the substitution $x=\sin\theta$ during integration, we might as well get everything on the right side of the equation in terms of sine.

$\sin3\theta=\left(2\sin\theta\cos\theta\right)\cos\theta+\left(1-2\sin^2\theta\right)\sin\theta$

$\sin3\theta=2\sin\theta\cos^2\theta+\sin\theta-2\sin^3\theta$

$\sin3\theta=2\sin\theta\left(1-\sin^2\theta\right)+\sin\theta-2\sin^3\theta$

$\sin3\theta=2\sin\theta-2\sin^3\theta+\sin\theta-2\sin^3\theta$

$\sin3\theta=3\sin\theta-4\sin^3\theta$

Now we can substitute $3\sin\theta-4\sin^3\theta$ in for $\sin3\theta$.

$\int\sin3\theta\cos\theta\ d\theta\to\int\left(3\sin\theta-4\sin^3\theta\right)\cos\theta\ d\theta$

From here. you're basically all set to use the substitution $x=\sin\theta$ and proceed with integrating as normal.